# Spring Security: Rest endpoint is not found after securing with @Secured

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-security

I am trying to secure a REST endpoint via the @Secured annotation of Spring Security. My main application (Spring Boot App) with the security config and the rest controller are in different packages and project.

Main app package: com.myapp.api.web

Rest controller packge: com.myapp.api.rest

Mainapp:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.myapp.api")
@EntityScan("com.myapp.api")
@RestController
public class ApiApplication extends SpringBootServletInitializer
{
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    SpringApplication.run(ApiApplication.class, args);
}

@Override
protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application)
{
    return application.sources(ApiApplication.class);
}
```

}

Security Config:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true, proxyTargetClass = true, 
securedEnabled = true)
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter
{
private static final String USERS_CONFIG_FILE_NAME = "users.yml";

@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception
{
    http
        .httpBasic()
        .and()
        .csrf().disable();

    http.sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);
}

@Bean
public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder()
{
    return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
}

@Autowired
public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth,
    InMemoryUserDetailsManager inMemoryUserDetailsManager, PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder) throws Exception
{
    auth.userDetailsService(inMemoryUserDetailsManager).passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder);
}

@Bean
public InMemoryUserDetailsManager inMemoryUserDetailsManager() throws IOException
{
    return new InMemoryUserDetailsManager(
        PropertiesLoaderUtils.loadAllProperties(USERS_CONFIG_FILE_NAME, getClass().getClassLoader()));
}
```

}

Rest controller:

```
@RestController
public class RestController
{

private final RestService service;

@PostMapping("/rest/v1")
@Secured({"ROLE_ADMIN"})
public List<String> getStates(@RequestBody List<String> Ids)
{
    ...
}
```

My rest endpoint is working as long as I am not setting *securedEnabled = true*. After setting it *true* I am getting a 404 Not Found as respond message. I've already debugged it and found out that the Spring Security somewhen stops in the filter chain and that the request never reaches the controller.

As far as I tested it, as long as the rest controller is in a different project this error will occure. After moving it to the same project it is working as it should.

Is there something missing in my Securityconfig or what could the problem be?

Comment: Try check if spring contains your user in the security context. `UserDetails userDetails =
 (UserDetails)SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal();`

Comment: Where(package) the `ApiApplication` and `SecurityConfiguration ` are?

Answer (score 0):

I am able to get values by your code , I have only changed Password Encoder to default and changed inMemoryAuthentication . 
I did it as I don't have your file "users.yml" If you can share a sample , we will look in it , But below is my code. I kept all logic in 2 files just to verify.

**Configuration Class**

```
package com.myapp.api.web.Api;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.method.configuration.EnableGlobalMethodSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.security.config.http.SessionCreationPolicy;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.password.PasswordEncoder;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true, proxyTargetClass = true, 
securedEnabled = true)
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter
{
private static final String USERS_CONFIG_FILE_NAME = "users.yml";

@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception
{
    http
        .httpBasic()
        .and()
        .csrf().disable();

    http.sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);
}
@Bean
public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
    return new PasswordEncoder() {
        @Override
        public String encode(CharSequence rawPassword) {
            return rawPassword.toString();
        }
        @Override
        public boolean matches(CharSequence rawPassword, String encodedPassword) {
            return rawPassword.toString().equals(encodedPassword);
        }
    };
}

@Override
protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder builder) throws Exception {
    builder.inMemoryAuthentication()
      .withUser("user").password("user").roles("USER")
      .and().withUser("admin").password("admin").roles("ADMIN");
}
/*
@Bean
public InMemoryUserDetailsManager inMemoryUserDetailsManager() throws IOException
{


    return new InMemoryUserDetailsManager(
        PropertiesLoaderUtils.loadAllProperties(USERS_CONFIG_FILE_NAME, getClass().getClassLoader()));
}*/
}
```

**Main Class**

```
package com.myapp.api.web.Api;

import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.security.access.annotation.Secured;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.myapp.api")
@RestController
@SpringBootApplication
public class ApiApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(ApiApplication.class, args);
    }
    @PostMapping("/rest/v1")
    @Secured({"ROLE_ADMIN"})
    public List<String> getStates(@RequestBody List<String> Ids)
    {
        return Ids;
       // ...
    }

}
```